# html download attribute automatically replaces colons with underscores

Tags: html, download

Considering this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download2).

Changing `download="w3logo"` to `download="w3:logo"` results in getting file named `w3_logo.jpeg`

1. What's the reason for such behaviour?
2. Is it o.k. to just use `U+02D0` instead of `U+003A` or there's a better solution?

Comment: `:` is not a valid filename character on Windows. Using `U+02D0` should be technically possible (although it carries an entirely different meaning) but I would discourage that because it will be confusing to users.

Comment: @CherryDT Oh yeah I totally forgot that windows don't support : as a valid filename character

Comment: @CherryDT, My software is only supposed to be working on linux. What would you advise if I need to show time in a filename? In my case user downloads a report and it is required to display time when it was generated in it's name...

Comment: I would use a dash or an underscore for it. Possibly a dot.